# jquery change div's background color to blink

Tags: jquery, html, background-color

I want to change the color of div and change it back to the original colur after a second. but I want to do it 2-3 times in a row to get the attention of the user.

here is the jquery code which changes the color to red and changes back to the original ONLY ONCE.

```
$('.b').on('click', function() {

var $el = $(".a"),
x = 500,
originalColor = $el.css("background");

$el.css("background", "red");
setTimeout(function(){
  $el.css("background", originalColor);
}, x);

});
```

How can I change the color and change it back 3 times?

Comment: This might be useful:  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/13046/javascript-repeat-a-function-x-times-at-i-intervals

Comment: setInterval instead of setTimeout and a var to keep track of how many times it's been called, then cancel the interval

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a recursive `setTimeout`:

```
$('.b').on('click', function () {
    var $el = $(".a"),
        x = 500,
        originalColor = $el.css("background"),
        i = 3; //counter

    (function loop() { //recurisve IIFE
        $el.css("background", "red");    
        setTimeout(function () {
            $el.css("background", originalColor);
            if (--i) setTimeout(loop, x); //restart loop
        }, x);
    }());
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ByakC/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.b').on('click', function() {
    var i     = 0,
        orgCl = $('.a').css("background"),
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            $('.a').css('background', 'red').delay(500).show(1, function() {
                $('.a').css('background', orgCl).delay(500).show(1, function() {
                    if (i++ > 2) clearInterval(timer);
                });
            });
        },1000);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/MBHQ3/)